# Deoptim and cross-validation

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, cross-validation

I try to reproduce this example :
[How to optimize parameters using genetic algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026436/how-to-optimize-parameters-using-genetic-algorithms)

with Deoptim, but I did not manage to do so.
Is there a way to add a function to the optimizer like in the GA package ?